# Simple modal not working

Tags: javascript, mootools, simplemodal

I have problem with simple modal! Is not working I got some errors! I have mootols and jquery in header.php

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addEvent' demo.js:8
(anonymous function) demo.js:8
(anonymous function) mootools-core-1.3.1.js:354
h mootools-core-1.3.1.js:32
Array.implement.each mootools-core-1.3.1.js:38
invoke.fireEvent mootools-core-1.3.1.js:353
h
```

My code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/simple-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you using mootools and jQuery at the same time? You don't think there's a million modal plugins out there for jQuery?

Comment: I try use fancybox! But have problem

Answer (score 2):

Move your last script tag to first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/simple-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

It will work..

or may be you have multiple instances of jQuery on your page.

You need to either:

- Aet rid of one of them (there's no need to have both)
- Alias the jQuery used in custom.js
- Use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to resolve which jQuery gets access to the $
  variable.